# SQL query in Laravel DB::raw() to order column and get first result

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to order a specific column in my `DB::raw()` select statement, I need to order the items for each day and get the first one for each day, so I'd end up with 5 results for 5 months but my error is

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

What am I missing?

```php
GoogleAnalytics::where('event_category', 'Category')
                ->where('event_action', 'Action')
                ->whereDate('period_from', '>=', '2021-06-08')
                ->whereDate('period_to', '<=', '2021-06-08')
                ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") as created_at'), DB::raw('FIRST(event_count ORDER BY created_at DESC ) as sessions'))
                ->groupByRaw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m")')
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

Some more context here, each day might have 100 entries, so there could be 3,000 entries per month, I need to get just a single entry in each day so I end up with 30 entries, and then add up those 30 result to produce a single result for that one month, so I'd end up with 5 items in my returned collection, but right now I can't seem to get `DB::raw('FIRST(event_count ORDER BY created_at DESC ) as sessions')` to grab the column, order it and just get the first result.

Comment: I don't think `FIRST` is a function at all, hence the error. Is the `event_count` column the same for all rows in a day?

Comment: `event_count` increments throughout the day and resets to 0 at the start of the following day, it's data pulled from Google Analytics, and I need the last result in each day over each day of the month added together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `FIRST` is a function at all, hence the error. If we break your problems into two you want:

1. *One* row for each day with the `event_count` column present. As per your comment above the column increments and you want the last value, thus you want the `max` value per day.
2. Sum the values of the `event_count` column, grouping by the month and year

**1:**

A select statement for this would look like

```sql
select date(created_at), max(event_count) from google_analytics group by date(created_at) where ...
```

Using the Eloquent builder it would look something like this:

```php
$query = GoogleAnalytics::select(
            DB::raw('date(created_at) as created_at'),
            DB::raw('max(event_count) as sessions')
        )
        ->where('event_category', 'Category')
        ->where('event_action', 'Action')
        ->whereDate('period_from', '>=', '2021-06-08')
        ->whereDate('period_to', '<=', '2021-06-08')
        ->groupByRaw('date(created_at)');
```

Note:

- your where clause only looks at one date (2021-06-08)
- this query will not return complete `GoogleAnalytics` models

**2:**

We can use the above `$query` to group the results per month:

```php
$result = DB::table($query, 'per_day')->select(
            DB::raw('date_format(created_at, "%Y-%m") as created_at'),
            DB::raw('sum(sessions) as sessions')
        )
        ->groupByRaw('date_format(created_at, "%Y-%m")')
        ->orderByRaw('date_format(created_at, "%Y-%m") desc')
        ->get();
```